# What are the dimensions of iOS custom disclosure indicators?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am looking to implement a custom disclosure indicator in a `UITableView`. Basically I need to make white indicators.

Apple documentation lists dimensions that are required for app icons for the retina and non-retina display, however I couldn't find recommended dimensions for items such as disclosure indictors.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what the appropriate dimensions would be to create disclosure icons for retina and non-retina displays?

And come to think of it how would the app know which one to pick?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For custom disclosure indicators you could just use `UITableViewCell`'s `accessoryView` property and set any size you want. If you are asking for disclosure indicator sizes that apple uses, they are: 58x62 for disclosure button, retina, and 19x28 for disclosure indicator, retina. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, what about retina vs non-retina. Do I need to make the non-retina half the size and give a special name for iOS to process? Or does it just size it smaller for non-retina?

Comment: For non-retina, you just give a simple name, for retina, you have to add `@2x` before extension, e.g. `image.png` for non-retina, and `image@2x.png` for retina (which is twice bigger in size than your `image.png`). Good luck!

Answer (score 19):

Our app uses white disclosure indicators in iOS 7.  To match the styling in iOS 6.1 and prior, we use a custom disclosure indicator image that corresponds exactly to the iOS 7 disclosure indicator.  We were able to obtain a pixel-perfect match with 26x28 disclosure@2x.png and 13x14 disclosure.png.

[image: disclosure@2x.png]
[image: disclosure.png]

Comment: cool, i'll use this in my UIViewCollection since it doesn't support cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;