# How to make UIAccessibility to treat all clickable UITableViewCell's as button without disclosure indicator?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiaccessibility

Currently, any `UITableViewCell` with disclosure indicator has an Accessibility Voiceover text ending in 'Button'. This seems to appear only when the disclosure indicator is turned on for that cell. Due to some design constraints, I'm unable to use disclosure indicator but am using an image in place of the disclosure indicator. In this case, how to force the voiceover to read the `UITableViewCell` as a button at the end as if a disclosure indicator were present?

Based on past experience I know some of you might ask for what code can you show? Since this is a conceptual question, apart from setting the table view cell to show disclosure indicator I do not have any code written. Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand. You want to use a custom image in place of the disclosure indicator, which has an accessibility voiceover text ending in 'button'?

Comment: @CaseyWest yes that is correct. Due to design constraints, I'm unable to accommodate default disclosure indicator and am choosing to use an image for disclosure indicator. Thank you for responding.

Comment: does this help you at all?  I am going to test some things as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930872/what-are-the-dimensions-of-ios-custom-disclosure-indicators

Comment: @CaseyWest thank you. I have dimensions as to how the disclosure indicator is going to look like. It doesn't address accessibility voiceover value to be announced in that answer. thank you though.